# Audio production with a non-linear editor that works from plain-text files

Tags: audio, plain-text, audio-editing

I am starting audio production after many years in software development. I have produced some audio for video in Final Cut Pro and now I want to go to the next level. After I finish the project, I may want to change some settings, which is cumbersome in FCPX (if I want to increase  sound adjustment from 10 dB to 11 dB, I need to select them by hand and adjust, instead of doing "find-and-replace" of 10 dB to 11dB). Also, the size of the Final Cut Pro project is quite large.

I am looking for an audio editor where the project file is plain text, which I understand to be an edit decision list (EDL). My goals are:

- to separate heavy digital assets from the light edit decision list
- to put the edit decision list into a version control system like Git and GitHub
- to automate some parts of editing, e.g. find-and-replace on pauses and dB levels
- to use standard audio production techniques: noise gate, noise removal, frequency spectrum adjustment, limiter, compressor, and depulsive filter (removing the pop's in the plosives B and P)

Ideally, the editor would be open source and work on macOS, but I'm open to anything.

I understand that Audacity does all of these except the plain-text part, which means that any edits are destructive, so "version-control" works by saving the project each time.

Three examples outside of audio production are AviSynth, whose Edit Decision Lists are very a few KB of text; OpenSCAD in 3D modelling, which generates STL files from plain-text files that are two orders of magnitude smaller; Inkscape, which reads and writes plain-text SVG files.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2):

You can [script](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html) Audacity from an external python script (with the output file being separate from the input file so as to provide non-destructive editing) with the scripts being plain text, python, files.

There is a huge selection of Audio processing and production software in the Python work some of which may provide what you need. A curated list can be found in the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic).

Comment: I like the ability to batch-process files, e.g. applying a compressor-limiter of segments of a file. I presume this is a more advanced solution; my idea was an entry-level program where I could work on the audio in real time and see the edit decision list in plain text at the same time.

Comment: @miguelmorin - it is worth noting that an Audacity project file (*.aup) __is__ plain text (in an XML format) and that Audacity edits __are__ non-destructive as long as you do not export the file over the original.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that Audacity files are plain text. The digital assets are saved at `<project name>_data/eff/d1b/eff1b038.au` and I can't immediately see the relation to the source files. I've had [trouble scripting Audacity](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/scripting-crashes-audacity) and noise reduction is [not available from scripting](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting_reference.html).